# How to use visual merging tools?

Tags: merge, beyondcompare, kdiff3

I can't get my head around KDiff3 or Beyond Compare in the merge mode.
Is there any tutorial to this feature?

Comment: I personally like to have good old conflict markers in the source

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a [video](http://www.scootersoftware.com/videos/CodeRage5/) showing how to use [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com) to merge files.  It was given as part of Embarcadero's [CodeRage 5](http://www.embarcadero.com/coderage5) conference, so it covers a lot of general usage as well.  The merge part begins at about 13:00.

Comment: The merge tutorial starts at minute 13 and ends at 20

Comment: @Reinis Thanks, we now have a copy on our site and I've updated the link.

Answer (score 2):

I found one tutorial at

http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/doc/merging.html

Answer (score 0):

http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/doc/merging.html
this link might help you.
but some rare facts are not considered at this link ...like "line end style"...for further conflicts